# Undefined Variable When sending via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form which passes the forn field values to an ajx script which then passes those values to php and they are they sent to an email address.

The problem i have is that the values are not showing and instead i get the word undefined.

Here is my ajax code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('form.save').submit(function () {
var name = $(this).find('.name').attr('value');
var email = $(this).find('.email').attr('value');
var telephone = $(this).find('.telephone').attr('value');
// ...
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "application.php",
        data: "name="+ name +"& email="+ email +"& telephone="+ telephone,
        success: function(){
            $('form.save').hide(function(){$('div.success')});
        }
    });
return false;
});
});
```

Here is my form

```
  <form action="" method="post" class="save">

                              <input type="text" name="name"  id="name" clsss="name" value="" placeholder="Name"/>

                              <input  type="text" name="email"  class="email" value="" placeholder="Email"/>


                              <input  type="text" name="telephone"  class="telephone" value=""placeholder="Telephone"/>

                            <input name="certified" type="checkbox" value="" checked>I am a Certified sophisticated Investor
                            <input type="hidden" name="type" value="Certified sophisticated Investor">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Submit"/>

                           </div>
                      </form>
```

And then the php (There is no sanitation on the php code i am just trying to get the value and will then use better php code)

```
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];


 // mail
 $msg = "$name $email $telephone";
 $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
 mail("*************","Application",$msg);
```

Comment: There is typo in your code , u have used clsss="name" instead of class="name"

Comment: why there space after ever `&` instead of this `& email` use this `&email`

Comment: @samWalker, try to use serialize function for sending your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things wrong in your code,

- See this statement here,

  ```
  <input type="text" name="name"  id="name" clsss="name" value="" placeholder="Name"/>
                                              ^ It should be class
  ```
- You're getting the input field values in the wrong way. It should be like this:

  ```
  var name = $(this).find('.name').val();
  var email = $(this).find('.email').val();
  var telephone = $(this).find('.telephone').val();
  ```

So your AJAX request should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form.save').submit(function () {
    var name = $(this).find('.name').val();
    var email = $(this).find('.email').val();
    var telephone = $(this).find('.telephone').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "application.php",
            data: {name:name, email:email, telephone:telephone},
            success: function(){
                $('form.save').hide(function(){$('div.success')});
            }
        });
    return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data: "name="+ name +"& email="+ email +"& telephone="+ telephone
```

Remove the spaces

```
data: "name="+ name +"&email="+ email +"&telephone="+ telephone
```

Answer (score 0):

send data to ajax as below :

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data : { 'foo' : bar, 'bar' : foo },
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object of key/value pairs :

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data : { 'name' : name, 'email' : email , 'telephone' : telephone},
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <form id="order-form">    <!--Try to add id for your form -->
    <!--your code here-->
    ...
    ...
 </form>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('form.save').submit(function () {
        var data = $("#order-form").serialize();  //You should use serialize for send data
          $.ajax({
            url: "/yourUrl",
            data: data,       
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (result) {
                 $('form.save').hide(function(){$('div.success')});
                 $("#renderarea").html(result); 
             }
            }); 
            return false;
        });
    }):
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will work fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('form.save').submit(function () {
var str = $( "form.save" ).serialize();


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getajax.php",
    data: str,
    success: function(){
        $('form.save').hide(function(){$('div.success')});
    }
});
return false;
});
});
```